# Azure Devops : Can I use single manual test plan against multiple tasks with seperate test results?

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

I have a Test plan A which will be executed across multiple platforms ex: windows, mac, android etc
and I want to record separate results against all the platforms but I don't want to clone the same test plan for all the platforms
is it feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is feasible.

1.First go to the Configurations page in Azure Test Plans

2.Then create a configuration variables.

3.Create a New test configuration and add the configuration variables to it

For more details, refer to
[this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/test-different-configurations?view=azure-devops#create-configurations-and-variables)

Comment: Thank you @mj1313 for your response